# My mechanic forgot to put Coolant and now my car is not work! what can i do? or who should i blame

Tags: engine, toyota, maintenance, coolant, scion

I had a small accident and I hit the whole front of my car and the radiator was damage.  I took it to my friends mechanic (which i though i could trust) and asked for an estimate. He owes a Bodyshop and knowing my situation he complied to fix the damage for a cost of $2000.  At first i though it was too much but since i needed my car for school i had to do it asap.
It took him 2 weeks to get back at me and told me the car was ready for pick up.
I went to pick up the car in the morning, and his brother was there and gave me a receipt and the keys to my car and verbally told me my car was ready to go.  On my way home i start noticing that my engine was making this funny noise.  About 5 miles or so my car breaks down, and the coolant gauge starts to signalize that its over heating. (keep in mind i was strangled in the middle of the Turnpike).  I called the mechanic and he told me he was on his way to check out my car and see what the problem seems to be.  As he arrives i notice he is holding a gallon of Coolant.  He opens my hood and without checking anything he begins to fill out my radiator. (how odd was that)  HE tells me that i should be ok now.. . As i leave maybe 2 miles later on my car shuts down again and this time it doesn't even respond at all.  I had to call AAA to come pick me up but since i was in a parkway they couldnt go in to get me so i had to spend money on a tow truck (not to make it long ) the following day i called the guy and he is not been reasonable to fix the damage.  And he keeps saying that he is a bodyshop not a mechanic. But yet he replaced my radiator.
i dont know wat to do at this point but im very angry that he doesnt wanna come clean and help me resolve this issue.  what can i do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue between you and your mechanic. Sorry, but it sounds like the engine may be destroyed, and this site is unable to offer legal advice on how to proceed.

Comment: I concur with @LynnCrumbling - This really is a legal matter which needs to be addressed with the mechanic who did the work.

Comment: I agree this is between the person and the shop. You may want to contact the BBB thou. They can possibly help you.

Comment: Indeed. Legal matter.  We could offer you help if you want really bad advice.   @dee 's suggestion of BBB or Attorney Gen of your State perhaps....but even that is too far.  There is a legal site on SE.     This could be a good place to go.     http://law.stackexchange.com/